# Looping a macro in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the macro further down to access and API. I have address in column A and Postcode in Column B. If i selects C1 and activate the macro it will look up the address+postcode and return a result. However, I want it to automatically do this for following rows. So after looking up A1 and B1 for a result in C1 I want it to look up A2 and B2 and give the result in C2 and so on and so forth for as long as I want..

How do I do this?

The macro:

```
Sub APIExecute()
'
' APIExecute Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
'
    Dim connectionString As String, quertable As QueryTable
    connectionString = "URL;https://www.conzoom.eu/Webservices/GetMosaic.aspx?address=" & _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("A1") & "&postcode=" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("B1")


    Set quertable = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connectionString, Destination:=ActiveCell)
    With quertable
        .FieldNames = False
        .RowNumbers = False
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = False
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .MaintainConnection = False
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .Refresh
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way is to use a For-Next loop.

Start off by adding `For i=1 to x` to the start of your sub where x is the number of rows you need it for. Then just change `Range("A1")` to `Range("A" & i)` and same for `B1`.

Finally, select your `C` range by changing `Destination:=ActiveCell` to `Destination:=Range("C" & i)` and stick yourself a `Next i` after your `End With`

Comment: Also, if you just needed the value adding for all your rows and didnt want to specify a number (x), you could just check for the last row of your range and use that number instead

Comment: I added those things, but i get error: "Variable not defined" for the i in "For i = 1 To X"

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you put in a value for x or used a row count to get a value?

Comment: You can also `Dim i as Long` so at least then `i` is always declared as a number

Comment: If you are not too sure on using `Rows.Count`, then this page may help your understanding: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm. In terms of the actual code required, you just need to add `x = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`, otherwise set `x = ` however many rows you are wanting to do it for